# Is there a verb to describe opening a can with a tab?

Tags: verbs

Is there a verb in the English language that describes the act of opening a can with a tab (like soda, for example). The closest I can get is "cracked open", but I'd like something more concise.

What about in other languages?

Comment: I'd have said if anything, *crack **open*** is *too* "concise". People just [crack a can of beer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cracked+a+can+of+beer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) about as often as they [crack **open** a can of beer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cracked+open+a+can+of+beer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Why use two words when one will do?

Comment: Also _pop_, but _crack_ has a better destructive feel to it.

Comment: I would likely say _pop,_ but I'm originally from [pop territory](http://www.popvssoda.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the turns of phrase "He pulled the tab on his beer." or "She popped the tab on her cooler." work nicely as alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

*Pop* cans are *popped* — of course. :)

More generally, one even speak of popping a beer can, at least if it has a pop-top cap (which I think all do).

Comment: These days many other types of can have ring-pulls, particularly those containing beans and tomatoes. Would you still refer to "popping" a can of food or other non-pressurised contents?